# Div `100%` height with `40px` bottom margin

Tags: html, css, transition, margin, padding

I know something similar has been asked before here.

But it's a little different as it involves `css transitions`.

http://jsfiddle.net/fariskassim/rWNJN/4/

```
.panel{

width:inherit;
height: 0%;
display:block;
position: absolute;

background: #000;
opacity:0;
z-index: 2;

margin-top: 40px;
margin-right: 40px;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-bottom: 40px;

bottom:0;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;

-webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
transition: all .8s ease-in-out;

}
```

When the box is opened,

i'm trying to get the green box have a `40px` on all sides from the browser perimeter, I've managed to do it for the left / right and top but bottom is a problem.

Any idea how do i fix this?

EDIT: at the same time, i still want the wipe in and out effect when opening and closing the box.

http://jsfiddle.net/fariskassim/rWNJN/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you have given `height:100%` in the `.panel:target`. Remove it then it will be fine.

```
.panel:target{

    background-color: rgba(226, 229, 16, 0.8);
    opacity:100;

    width:inherit;
    display:block;

    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;

    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rWNJN/6/)**

Comment: oh thanks alot! this works. also i fiddled with the bottom position to keep the wipe effect. http://jsfiddle.net/fariskassim/rWNJN/9/

Answer (score 2):

**Whatever you want** + Responsive height

```
.panel:target{

    background-color: rgba(226, 229, 16, 0.8);
    opacity:100;
    height: auto;

    width:inherit;
    display:block;

    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

[auto adjust demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/rWNJN/8/)

Comment: hmm but it pretty much screws up  the wipe effect no?

Comment: Yes, because `height:auto` measures browser height first before key-frame animation could take place. I have refined fiddle for proper alignment.

Comment: ah alright, got the thing to work by messing a little with the other answer. thanks alot though.